# Microsoft Edge Extensions - Can we submit them? Is there an update page?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Can I submit my extension to the Windows store? If not, how will I know when Edge has opened this capability for all developers? Is there some update page or Twitter account or something (anything!) that I am missing!?

I just noticed that there are now more extensions than I remember there being a few weeks ago, but is it still by invitation only?

I already ported and tested my extension in Edge.

I'm sorry that this is not a coding question, but I'm tired of every other week trying to find this information to make sure that my extension becomes available as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated (12/19/2016):

Microsoft Edge has published the [packaging documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/guides/packaging/).

### Previous:

If you're interested in deploying extensions to Windows Store, you could submit a request to https://aka.ms/extension-request to be considered for a future update.

For update page, [Microsoft Edge Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/) and [Microsoft Edge Extensions Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/) may help.

Comment: Thanks for this. The extensions documentation makes it all seem like extensions are ready, except they aren't. The blog is more aimed at users, it seems, and has an article about the extensions that you can now download from the store. It's just strange to me that they aren't clearer about the status...

Comment: @user984003, you may want to have a look at extensions session in Ignite, https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/New-Zealand-2016/M357